# Arrays jumping over each other - Tile based algorithm game

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, iteration

I´m having difficulties with a game I am trying to program with Javascript which goes like this:
[image: Game Concept]

```
var Game = {
stage: new createjs.Stage($("#stage")),
tileSrcs : ["img/green-mushroom.png" , "img/red-mushroom.png" , "img/blue-mushroom.png"],
tiles : [],
level : [1,1,1,0,2,2,2],
winState: [2,2,2,0,1,1,1],
```

I hope you get where Im going with this so the game ends when a user gets all the blue mushroom to the left side and the red mushroom are on the right side.

```
1 1 1 0 2 2 2 - > Starting point
1 1 0 1 2 2 2 - > Red mushroom moves one to the right
1 1 2 1 0 2 2 - > Blue can then jump over red and land on the other side of it.
```

My code so far looks like this:

```
Game.Tile = function (myX, myY, myType) {
var my = new createjs.Bitmap(Game.tileSrcs[myType]);
my.type = myType;
my.posX = myX;
my.posY = myY;

my.update = function () {
    my.image.src = Game.tileSrcs[my.type];
};

my.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
    var nextX;
    if (my.type === 1) {
        my.type = 0;
        nextX = my.posX + 1;
        Game.tiles[nextX].type = 1;
    }   else if (my.type === 2){
        my.type = 0;
        nextX = my.posX - 1;
        Game.tiles[nextX].type = 2;}
    Game.update();
});
return my;
};
```

I put the game up on a free web host just so you could see what problem I am dealing with at the moment. The blue ones are going in the right direction but they are not jumping over reds, they are more overwriting them and the same goes for the red mushrooms when they go to the right.

I hope I have been thorough enough, if not, please let me know.

The website is:
http://smallisax.net16.net/MovingMushrooms/index.html

(You might need to refresh the page once, if there is nothing showing at first)

Thanks alot,

Comment: `Game.tiles[nextX].type = *;` also has to handle the CURRENT tile. you only update the one before/after the click position, but don't actually change the one that got clicked on.

Comment: Hey there MarcB, thanks for your reply. By that do you mean I have to create a new function maybe called currentX and then give it if/else statements?

Comment: no. the game just requires swapping two tiles. but your code only ever updates ONE tile. so whatever you click on "infects" the next stage to the left or right.